# React native Typescript Touchableopacity props error

Tags: typescript, react-native, touchableopacity, onpress

I have created one reusable button by using Styled component and Typescript. I made  `onPress` void. I am using this button to the [headStyles](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons). HeaderStyles have a one prop name `headerLeft`.  `headerLeft's` props' onPress is optional or undefined. When I am passing this props to my Button then I got Typescript error as expected. This is the error: `Type '(() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)`. Is there any way I made `headerLeft` props onPress void?

**This is my reuseable Button component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';


type Props = {
  onPress: () => void;
};
const BackButtonContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  padding-vertical: 16px;
  padding-horizontal: 24px;
`;

const Button = ({ onPress }: Props) => {
  return (
    <BackButtonContainer
      onPress={onPress}>
   
    </BackButtonContainer>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

**This is headerStyles**

```
import { StackNavigationOptions } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import Button from './buttons;

export const headerStyles: StackNavigationOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    elevation: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 },
  },
  headerTitleAlign: 'center',
  headerTintColor: colors.greyGradient[800],
  headerLeft: (props) =>
    props.canGoBack ? <Button onPress={props.onPress} /> : null, //In here I am getting typescript error

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sure you have `onPress` from `headerLeft` props, you can use `!` to inform typescript there must be `onPress()` and it will not be undefined:

```
headerLeft: (props) =>
    props.canGoBack ? <Button onPress={props.onPress!} /> : null,
```

More on [non-null assertion operator - `!`](http://headerLeft:%20(props)%20=%3E%20%20%20%20%20props.canGoBack%20?%20%3CButton%20onPress=%7Bprops.onPress%7D%20/%3E%20:%20null,)

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: In my button I am using react native's AccessibilityRole&AccessibilityState. I made the type like this: https://codeshare.io/oQPqdr

Comment: your code works fine on my side. no type error. If you hover on `hint`, is it `string | undefined`? maybe you can try `Platform.select<string | undefined>({ ios: hint });`

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are really Typescript master 

Comment: When  I used this to my button it throws Typescript error also:

  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<TouchableOpacityProps & RefAttributes<TouchableOpacity>, never> & Partial<Pick<TouchableOpacityProps & RefAttributes<...>, never>>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; accessibilityLabel: string | undefined; accessibilityHint: string | undefined; accessibilityRole: AccessibilityRole | undefined; accessibilityState: AccessibilityState | undefined; testID: string |

Comment: If you have time, is there possibility to chat with you?

Comment: ok. sure. seems like you are making your project from js to ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233592/discussion-between-krisna-and-mic-fung).